# The change event is not getting triggered in case syncfusion ejs-multiselect control is used in Ag-Grid custom cell editor

Tags: angular, ag-grid, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion ejs-multiselect control as a custom cell editor in Ag-grid. In this the change event is not getting fired when multi-select value is changed and some other cell is clicked. How ever if clicked out of Ag-grid, change event is getting fired. (i am using in my existing project)
As in case of creating a new project and trying same, it is working fine.
Following are package.json file(in case it is of any version issue)

**package.json:**

```
{
      "name": "portal",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
        "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.29",
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^7.1.1",
        "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.1",
        "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/material": "^6.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
        "@markpieszak/ng-application-insights": "^7.0.3",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^17.2.49",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns": "^17.3.14",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs": "^17.2.52",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^17.1.43",
        "ag-grid-angular": "^21.2.2",
        "ag-grid-community": "^21.2.2",
        "ag-grid-enterprise": "^21.2.2",
        "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
        "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "indexeddb-angular": "^0.1.8",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.10",
        "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
        "ngx-breadcrumbs": "0.0.3",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
        "ngx-drag-drop": "^2.0.0",
        "ngx-monaco-editor": "^6.0.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.110",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.2.2"
      }
    }
```

The code is normal:
**app.component** includes ag-grid:

```
HTML file:    

<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" 
    [singleClickEdit]="true"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>

TS File:    

    export class AppComponent {
      holdValue:any=["Hello"];
      ngOnInit(): void {
        //throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
      }
      private frameworkComponents;

      columnDefs = [
          {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make', editable: true, cellEditor:'multi',width:300, cellEditorParams: this.holdValue },
          {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model', editable: true,cellEditor:'text',width:300, cellEditorParams: this.holdValue },
          {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price', editable: true}
      ];

      rowData = [
          { make: '', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
          { make: '', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
          { make: '', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
      ];

      constructor() {

        this.frameworkComponents ={
          multi: MulticomponentComponent
        }
        }
    }
```

**Custom Cell Editor** "MulticomponentComponent" used  has following code:

```
HTML file:     

<ejs-multiselect id='multiselectelement' [dataSource]='sportsData' [fields]='fields' [(value)]="value"
[placeholder]='placeholder' (change)="OnChange($event)"></ejs-multiselect>


TS File:           

export class MulticomponentComponent implements ICellEditorAngularComp, AfterViewInit  {
  value:any=[];
  public sportsData: Object[] =  [
    { id: 'Game1', sports: 'Badminton' },
    { id: 'Game2', sports: 'Basketball' },
    { id: 'Game3', sports: 'Cricket' },
    { id: 'Game4', sports: 'Football' },
    { id: 'Game5', sports: 'Golf' }
];
// maps the appropriate column to fields property
public fields: Object = { text: 'sports', value: 'id' };
  public placeholder: string = 'Select games';
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }
  getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  agInit(params: import("ag-grid-community").ICellEditorParams): void {

  }
  OnChange(e){
    console.log("change occur");
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue is multiselect control destroyed when you click other grid cell because Ag-Grid destroyed the control. So, at that time none of the events will trigger other than destroy event. So, if you need to perform any operation while clicking on the other grid cell then you can use the destroy event.

```
<ejs-multiselect id='multiselectelement' [dataSource]='sportsData' [fields]='fields' [(value)]="value" [placeholder]='placeholder' (select)="select($event)" (destroyed)="onDestroyed($event)" (change)="OnChange($event)"></ejs-multiselect>
```

Also, when you click the outside of ag-grid, the control not destroyed. So, at that time change events will trigger.